# Using remote android sdk to build android applications

Tags: android

I'm building my android applications on a debian server A with local android sdk properly installed.

Now I want to build applications on another server B, which could reach server A through local network but without android sdk installed locally.

Can I just use sdk from server A to help building on server B?

Say export ANDROID_HOME=serverA:/sdk e.g.?